# Copy text within quotes and paste it on the same line?

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to edit a batch file for a text-to-speech thing I'm working on.

Basically, I wanna turn this:

```
"SAY SOMETHING"
"SAY SOMETHING ELSE"
"ALSO SAY THIS"
```

Into this:

```
voice -v 100 -r -2 -n "Microsoft Zira Desktop" -o "SAY SOMETHING.wav" -d "SAY SOMETHING"
voice -v 100 -r -2 -n "Microsoft Zira Desktop" -o "SAY SOMETHING ELSE.wav" -d "SAY SOMETHING ELSE"
voice -v 100 -r -2 -n "Microsoft Zira Desktop" -o "ALSO SAY THIS.wav" -d "ALSO SAY THIS"
```

Can it be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((".+)")$`
- Replace with: `voice -v 100 -r -2 -n "Microsoft Zira Desktop" -o $2.wav" -d $1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (           # group 1
        (           # group 2
            "           # double quote
            .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
        )           # end group 2
        "           # double quote
    )           # end group 1
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
voice -v 100 -r -2 -n "Microsoft Zira Desktop" -o       # literally
$2                  # content of group 2
.wav" -d            # literally
$1                  # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]